# How to create a randomly generated user profile within a city boundary in Geodjango?

Tags: python, django, gis, postgis, geodjango

Disclaimer: I have limited knowledge in python.I asked this question in gis.stackexchange, but was voted "unclear what you are asking", may be because it is a programming question, not gis?

I have used randomly generate users python script from this [source](https://github.com/andilabs/fuckfinder/blob/master/api/management/commands/generate_1M_ff_users.py) , while the command creates a postgis table, it does not create the randomly generate user profile (the table is empty). What is missing in creating the random user profile in the postgis table?

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point
import random
import uuid
import numpy as np
from mymap_app.models import LoveFinderUser


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'generate 1M users for Addis_Ababa with random sex, age, radius, location'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        Addis_Ababa__lat__min = 8.834544
        Addis_Ababa__lat__max = 9.099231
        Addis_Ababa__lng__min = 38.640241
        Addis_Ababa__lng__max = 38.907086

        for i in xrange(10**5):
            new_random_lat = random.uniform(Addis_Ababa__lat__min, Addis_Ababa__lat__max)
            new_random_lng = random.uniform(Addis_Ababa__lng__min, Addis_Ababa__lng__max)
            user_age = random.randrange(18, 55)
            user_delta_plus = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13])
            user_delta_minus = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13])
            user_sex = random.choice(['F', 'M'])
            user_prefered_sex=random.choice(['F', 'M'])

            new_user=LoveFinderUser.objects.create(
                nickname=str(uuid.uuid4()),
                age=user_age,
                sex=user_sex,
                prefered_sex=user_prefered_sex,
                prefered_age_min=(user_age-user_delta_minus),
                prefered_age_max=(user_age+user_delta_plus),
                last_location=Point(float(new_random_lng), float(new_random_lat)),
                prefered_radius=random.choice([5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30])
            )
            new_user.save()
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect to find that is missing? There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the code. You could try to add a simple `print(new_user)` after saving to confirm that new users are created.

Comment: @HåkenLid The code runs without error in PyCharm, but does not print or create new_user.

Comment: So how can you tell that the code was actually executed? This is a management command, so it's meant to be manually triggered from a command line / shell.

Comment: Yes, I run it both from cmd and PyCharm using the command and it runs without error: (myvenv_python3) python3 C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\MyProject\myapp\management\commands\generate_1M_LL_users.py

Comment: You have to run it with `manage.py` because that takes care of setting up django (connecting to the database, loading settings, logging etc.)
django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: So if `myapp` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`, you can try `django-admin generate_1M_LL_users` or `C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\MyProject\manage.py generate_1M_LL_users`

Comment: @HåkenLid Thank you very much for the answer. I used the command :
(myvenv_python3)django-admin generate_1M_LL_users and it worked, also i had to change xrange to range.

Comment: @HåkenLid Thank you very much for the answer. I used the command from the project directory:
(myvenv_python3)C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\myproject> django-admin generate_1M_LL_users and it worked, also i had to change xrange to range.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @HåkenLid. I used the command from the project directory: (myvenv_python3)C:\Users\Kaleab\Desktop\myproject> django-admin generate_1M_LL_users and it worked, also i had to change xrange to range.